# Hiding text using Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and trying to hide part of a page. I am fairly new to this stuff so apologies in advance if I am using the wrong terms or the question seems obvious!

The page format appears as below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">...</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
  <quote>...</quote>
  "*** I can't figure how to hide this ***"
  <p></p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">...</span>
  <div class="block-footer">...</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
</div>
```

As the snippet suggests, I cannot figure out how to hide the bit highlighted with stars.

I have a function that takes as an input a variable that is the first element in class "wrapper":

```
function processComment(commentStart)
{
    $element = commentStart;

    while($element)
    {
        if(some condition)
        {
            $element.hide();
        }
        $element.next();
    }
```

Because this text is sitting by itself outside any tags, it is not being picked up. I can't just hide the whole of the wrapper class because there are some bits inside it that I need to show.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I like the elegance of Pranav's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set visibility propery or wrapper as collapse and set visibility of childrens to visible for overriding visibility property. That it will only hide the text node.

```js
$('.wrapper').css('visibility', 'collapse').find('*').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">...</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
  <quote>...</quote>
  "*** I can't figure how to hide this ***"
  <p></p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">...</span>
  <div class="block-footer">...</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav. This is a neat solution. In my case I could write:

Comment: $element.parent().css('visibility', 'collapse').find('*').css('visibility', 'visible');

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to place the content you want hidden into a span of its own.

Comment: Thanks Tozer, I have no control of the format of the content but your suggestion would work if I did.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand, your `if (some condition)` is regarding the text content by itself, so it's a regex stuff or something like.

So what you can do is, having located the involved text part, wrap it between `<span>` tags: then you can address this `<span>` element the usual way.

It may look like this (here assuming your meta-example meant `$element`s are successive words):

```
function processComment(comment) {
    // (comment is supposed to be the HTML element to process)
    var words = $(comment).html().split(' ');
    for (var i in words) {
        var word = words|i];
        if(some condition on word) {
            words[i] = '<span class="hidden-word">' + word + '</span>';
        }
    }
    $(comment).html(words.join(' '));
}
```